# Qml incorrect mapping global coordinates

Tags: qt, qml

In this code section I created simple example with window and rectangle inside. I set x = 100 and y = 100 inner coordinates for rectangle. When I mapped these coordinates to global and get incorrect result, coordinates always  2 times more then in reality. For example if I set x and y equal 50 the result will be 50*2 = 100. Why this works incorrectly? And how can I fixed it?

```
    import QtQuick 2.15
    import QtQuick.Window 2.15
    
    Window {
        id: root
    
        width: 640; height: 480; visible: true;
        title: qsTr("Hello World")
        onXChanged: innerRect.globalChanged();
        onYChanged: innerRect.globalChanged()
        onWidthChanged: innerRect.globalChanged();
        onHeightChanged: innerRect.globalChanged()
    
        Rectangle {
            id: innerRect
    
            signal globalChanged()
            property point globalPoint
            onGlobalChanged: {
                innerRect.globalPoint = mapToGlobal(innerRect.x, innerRect.y)
            }
            color: "yellow"
            width: parent.width / 2; height: parent.height / 2
    
            x: 100; y: 100
    
            Text {
                id: xCoord
    
                anchors.left: parent.left;
                anchors.leftMargin: 20
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                text: "Gx: " + innerRect.globalPoint.x + " Wx: " + root.x
            }
            Text {
                id: yCoord
    
                anchors.right: parent.right;
                anchors.rightMargin: 20
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                text: "Gy: " + innerRect.globalPoint.y + " Wy: " + root.y
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `mapToGlobal` with incorrect arguments. The documentation says:

> Maps the point (x, y), which is in this item's coordinate system, to the global coordinate system, and returns a point matching the mapped coordinate.

In your code you are mapping the 100, 100 point relative to the rectangle's coordinate system to the global coordinate system. If you want to map the top left point of the rectangle, just call `mapToGlobal(0,0)`. Keep in mind that `mapToGlobal` is a member function, so you are calling `innerRect.mapToGlobal(innerRect.x, innerRect.y)` in your code.